# The method filter(FilterBuilder) in the type FilterAggregationBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (BoolQueryBuilder)

Tags: elasticsearch, search, group-by, aggregator

Am trying to group and subgroup in an elastic query, first by ipgroup and then by priority.

```
TermsBuilder ipGroupAgg = AggregationBuilders.terms("by_ipGroup").field("IP Group")
                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("by_Priority").field("Priority"));
        // create the bool filter for the condition above
        String[] priority= { "2", "3" };
        BoolQueryBuilder aggFilter = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("Priority", priority));

        // create the filter aggregation and add the year sub-aggregation
        FilterAggregationBuilder aggregation = AggregationBuilders.filter("agg").filter(aggFilter).subAggregation(ipGroupAgg );
```

But the last statement gives compile error stating "The method filter(FilterBuilder) in the type FilterAggregationBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (BoolQueryBuilder)" for the **filter(aggFilter)**

Comment: which version of ES are you using? Seems ES 1.7 or earlier, right?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using an old version of ES, my guts tell me 1.7 or earlier...
In this case you need to use the following code to create `aggFilter`:

```
    BoolFilterBuilder aggFilter = FilterBuilders.boolFilter().must(FilterBuilders.termsFilter("Priority", priority));
```

Comment: yes, it did not give errors, but however grouping and subgrouping is not happening

Comment: that's another issue then ;-) probably related to the query itself. Feel free to update your question with the raw JSON query that gets generated and we can debug it. Also provide your index mapping.